# Formatted amount to database format

Tags: php, mysql, format

hi I have a problem on formatted amounts.
On my input form, users can add and edit a formatted amount. Since this is a multi-language program, users can specify their own format, so there isn't a fixed pattern.
Examples:

```
250.000
250,000
250.000,00  
250,000.00
```

Sadly, I have to "un-format" them, before store them into the database or MySQL will understand my number as floats and viceversa.

How can I overcome this? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to know what culture/number format they are using. You can either have them tell you, or you can tell them how they must provide it - but you cant magically decide for them with reliability. Once you know what format/culture they are using you can convert back and forth appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, finally I made it, so I'll share my solution
First of all, I used [Mootools](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Number.Format) to format the input field while to user is typing.
Then I moved server side.

Format options are saved inside my application, so this is the code

```
//get decimal separator from saved params
$dec = $params->get('decimalSep', '.');
//remove any char that's not a number or decimal separator 
//(i don't care about thousands sep)
$regex = '#[^0-9-'.preg_quote($dec).']#';

$normalized = preg_replace($regex, '', $price);
$normalized = str_replace($dec, '.', $normalized);
```

Basically I get rid of everything except the decimal separator, then I replace it with the standard one (`.`).

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go on the side of allowing the users to enter what they want, in which case you'll ahve to sanitize (and translate in the case of the decimal symbol), as you guess here. Or you can restrict what they enter and force them to leave out thousand separators.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to check the localization of the client and accordingly parse the data that way. coz 2,500.00 = 2.500,00. It depends on the location.
2. Do not let the users enter ",".
3. Have a separate box to let users enter things after the decimal.
4. Let the box be pre-filled with 0.00. Telling the user this is the format.

Answer (score 0):

- Taking input from user in a proper format is a good way, put a viewable format message displayed near the input area.
- You should validate the input data when user perform submit.
- You can validate using regular expression in both JavaScript and in your server-side programming language before storing the user-input directly into the database.